# nodejs-websocket detect non-websocket connection attempt

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am running a websocket service using the nodejs-websocket module.

I would like to detect and take some action when a connection attempt is made that is not using websocket protocols.

I've thought of using setTimeout(n) and clearing the timeout when conn.readystate changes from 'connecting' to 'open' or taking an action upon the timer expiring but I'm hoping that there is a more direct way.

How can I detect a non-websocket connection attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webocket protocol starts every connection with an HTTP request with a header set that "requests" an upgrade to the webSocket protocol.  When both the server agrees, it responds with the upgrade and both client and server then change the protocol to the webSocket protocol.

So, a non-webSocket connection attempt will either be a plain HTTP connection or it will be just a socket connection attempt that isn't even HTTP.  So, in either case, the connection will die at the HTTP server either as a 404 (an HTTP request that the web server doesn't have a response for) or as an invalid protocol (not HTTP).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'd rather a solution that doesn't require a separate web server for my requirement but what you said is correct.

Comment: @RoyHB - you cannot detect an incoming webSocket connection (and non-webSocket request) without having at least a bare bones server capable of responding to an HTTP request because every webSocket request starts as an HTTP request.  So, without at least the bare bones HTTP server, you can't accept an incoming webSocket request.  If nodejs-webSocket supports incoming webSocket requests, then it is already an HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Connection has an error event, so you can do `Connection.on('error', function(err) ...`. This will mean something went wrong on the connection, but I don't believe you can do anything with the connection at that point.

One suggestion would be to use [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) which can party on an HTTP/Connect/Express server. It can speak HTTP(Kinda) or WebSockets. Then you could do something like:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http')
  .Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    hello: 'world'
  });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('news', {
    hello: 'world'
  });
  socket.on('my other event', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

This has all the Socket.io connections under the `/Socket.io/*` path. Any other connection will get handled by the `app.get('/*',...)` call. This would only catch http requests.

Comment: A non-webSocket connection will never get to socket.io so you won't be able to use socket.io's error handling.  What actually happens depends upon what kind of connection the non-webSocket connection actually is.

Comment: Yeah you're totally right. Engine.io (the thing that Socket.io runs on) consumes all requests and it never hits Express.You can see that with `DEBUG=*`. You could theoretically plug into the underlying Engine.io framework, but they don't make it obvious how. I tried a few simple things and couldn't get anything working. My answer probably won't work for you. You might need to implement/find something to handle a request based on the format of the request.